# Having trouble changing a UIBarButtonItem's image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying various ways of changing a UIBarButtonItem's image once it has been pressed, without any luck.

```
// bookmarkButton is a property linked up in IB
-(IBAction)bookmarkButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"this action triggers");
// attempt 1
UIBarButtonItem* aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmarkdelete.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(bookmarkButtonTapped:)];
bookmarkButton = aBarButtonItem;
[aBarButtonItem release];

// attempt 2
bookmarkButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmarkdelete.png"];
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar contains an array - items - as a property. So after setting up the toolbar as an IBOutlet property, I had to insert a new button into that array.. like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.toolBar.items];
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newButton.png"]  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
[items replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newButton];
self.toolBar.items = items;
[newButton release];
[items release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is bookmarkButton a UIButton?  Should it be referenced via `(UIButton *)aBarButtonItem.customView` instead of directly?

If it is a UIButton then you'll want to set the image based on state: `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`

Note that there is also a `setBackgroundImage` with the same API if you want that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
UIImage *normalButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewIcon"];
UIImage *selectedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CollectionViewIcon"];
CGRect rightButtonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, normalButtonImage.size.width,
                                     normalButtonImage.size.height);
UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rightButtonFrame];
[rightButton setBackgroundImage:normalButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton setBackgroundImage:selectedButtonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleTableView:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
self.toggleMediaView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.toggleMediaView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score -3):

try `[bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmarkdelete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: I get an error 'UIBarButtonItem' may not respond to -setImage:forState:' when I try that.